# Ejabberd Migration from 23 to 24

Tags: migration, erlang, ejabberd

After migrate ejabberd version 23.04 to 24.02 we are getting error to start with node name as ip.

We are try to run the below command to get the status get the error

sbin/ejabberdctl --node ejabberd@10.0.1.18 start - always started as localhost (I am not sure)

sbin/ejabberdctl --node ejabberd@10.0.1.18 status

Can't set long node name!
Please check your configuration